# Access a Bootcamp Windows 7 localhost on iPad

Tags: windows, macos, ipad, localhost, bootcamp

I'm developing on Visual Studio 2012 which loads a site on localhost and I'm trying to access this through my iPad for testing purposes on the same network.

Visual Studio is installed on Windows 7 which is running on Bootcamp.

Could anyone tell me if this is possible to do?

I can easily access the mac localhost on my iPad however I've been struggling to do it from the Windows 7 Bootcamp install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, perhaps you should try [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).   They're both stack exchange sites, one dedicated to Mac user questions, and the other to power users.

Comment: How are you serving up the "localhost" content when you're in Bootcamp?

Comment: I'm using IIS Express and loading the page app via Visual Studio 2012 which loads the address http://localhost:30320/name-of-the-app

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access it by giving the ipv4 address of the host machine on the network... I do this when testing sites for responsiveness. So for example,

```
http://192.168.0.6:30320/name-of-the-app/folder/file.aspx
```

Should work on any device, mobile, tablet etc that is attached to your network... I say should because I haven't tried this on IIS, but it seems to work fine using php.

My advice would be, on the instance running your server, get onto terminal command prompt and get your ip-address... then do the above!